# Lie group structure induced by a surjective group homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups

Let $H$ be a group and $G$ a connected Lie group. Suppose we have a surjective group $f:H \to G$, whose kernel is finite lying in $H$'s centre $Z(H)$. The question is, how to show that $H$ has a unique Lie group structure such that $f$ is also a Lie group homomorphism, as well as a [covering map](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoveringMap.html).

My attempt was identifying $V_i = f^{-1}(U_i)$ and $\psi_i = \varphi_i \circ f$ for the atlas of $H$ while $(U_i,\psi_i)_i$ is an atlas for $G$. But I think my attempt solved nothing at all. Perhaps I had only used surjectivity of $f$, meanwhile I guess the finiteness of its kernel, and the connectedness of $G$, should have been used already.

Would you like to give any hint or a proof for this question? I found no document teaching this on the internet :(

Comment: the problem with your attempt is that the restriction of $f$ to $V_i$ is not injective and thus $\phi_i\circ f$ cannot be bijective, so it can't be used to define a chart. What you need to show is that (for sufficiently small $U_i$) the preimage decomposes into a disjoint unsion of $|ker(f)|$ many subsets such that the restriction of $f$ to each of them is bijective. I am not quite sure how to do this in a general setting.